# Using loops to get multiple values into a cell

Tags: matlab, loops, cell

I have 31 subjects (S1, S2, S3, S4, etc.). Each subject has 3 images, contrast1.img, contrast2.img, and contrast3.img. I would like to use a loop to get all paths to the contrasts from all the subjects into a nx1 cell called P. P should be something like this:

> Data/S1/contrast1.img
>
> Data/S1/contrast2.img
>
> Data/S1/contrast3.img
>
> Data/S2/contrast1.img
>
> Data/S2/contrast2.img
>
> Data/S2/contrast3.img
>   ...
>
> Data/S31/contast3.img

This is what I've tried:

```
A={'S1','S2','S3',...,'S31'}; % all the subjects 
C={'contrast1.img','contrast2.img','contrast3.img'}; % contrast images needed for each subject

P=cell(31*3,1)

for i=1:length(A)

    for j=1:length(C)

     P{j}=spm_select('FPList', fullfile(data_path, Q{i}) sprintf('%s',cell2mat(C(j)))); % this is to select the three contrast images for each subject. It works in my script. It might not be 100% correct here since I had to simplify for this example.

    end

end
```

This, however, only give me P with the 3 contrast images of the last subject. Previous subjects get overwritten. This indicates that the loop is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

No loop needed. Use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate the combinations of numbers, [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) with left alignment to convert to strings, and [`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) to concatenate without trailing spaces:

```
M = 31;
N = 3;

[jj ii] = ndgrid(1:N, 1:M);
P = strcat('Data/S',num2str(ii(:),'%-i'),'/contrast',num2str(jj(:),'%-i'),'.img')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you assign P{j}.

Since j only loops 1:3 and doesn't care about i, you are just rewriting all three values for P{j}. I think you want to concatenate the new values to the cell array instead

```
for i=1:length(A)

    for j=1:length(C)

        P ={P; spm_select('FPList', fullfile(data_path, Q{i}) sprintf('%s',cell2mat(C(j))));}

    end

end
```

or you could assign each value directly such as

```
for i=1:length(A)

    for j=1:length(C)

        P{3*(i-1)+j} =spm_select('FPList', fullfile(data_path, Q{i}) sprintf('%s',cell2mat(C(j))));

    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Are you sure about P{i+3*(i-1)+j}?

Comment: Good catch, it should just be P{3*(i-1)+j}, which I updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cell matrix, which directly represents the subject index and the contrast index.

To preallocate use `P=cell(length(A),length(C))` and to fill it use `P{i,j}=...`

When you want to access the 3rd image of the 5th subject, use `P{5,3}`

Comment: Thank you for your response! This almost works but P has to be a 93x1 cell and the images has to be in the same order as I mentioned in my original message (i.e. sorted by subjects then sorted by contrasts).